# Access Id of hidden DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a hidden Div which is made visible on click of button. On page reload i want to keep the div still visible if i have clicked the button earlier. If not i want to keep the div hidden. I cannot get the id of the Div on click of the button.

for eg:

var id = document.getElementById("#<%= lblChartGUID.ClientID %>").attr('id') returns null reference.

I am trying to store this id and its visibility in local storage and retreive it on pageload.

Any help???????

Comment: Just use `var id = "<%= lblChartGUID.ClientID %>"`, that the ID

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that you are mixing Vanilla JS and jQuery

Use

```
var id = "<%= lblChartGUID.ClientID %>" // This is the simplest
```

*JQuery*

```
var id = $("#<%= lblChartGUID.ClientID %>").attr('id')
```

*Vanilla JS*

```
var id = document.getElementById("<%= lblChartGUID.ClientID %>").getAttribute('id')
```

Answer (score 0):

This  `var id = document.getElementById("#<%= lblChartGUID.ClientID %>").attr('id')` is completely wrong. You're mixing up javascript and jquery.

Just do:

```
var id='<%= lblChartGUID.ClientID %>';
```

Answer (score 0):

why do you need to get the id if its already there.you can simply use:

```
 var id="<%= lblChartGUID.ClientID %>";
```

or to fetch id by using jquery object of element use:

```
 var id=$("#<%= lblChartGUID.ClientID %>").attr('id');
```